# Struts2 property tag escapeHtml is not working am I missing something?

Tags: struts2

The following code is not working correctly.  I would like to take the following Java String from the bean

```
String statusMsg = "Hello World! <br/><br/><h3>Test</h3>"
```

And output it with the HTML tags not escaped.

```
<s:property escapeHtml="false" value="bean.statusMsg"
```

The result of this property Tag and String, is that the HTML tags are still being escaped, am I missing something?

My goal is to eventually build a table of status data and output it on the page is this the wrong way to use the property tag?  Thank you in advance for your help.

The current output is the following

```
Hello World! <br/><br/><h3>Test</h3>
```

I would like it to use the tags and add a couple of new lines and make Test a header.  This is all test code right now, just trying to get it to work.

Comment: see my updated post i cross checked this at my system and this is working fine for me

Comment: just show JSP page and action class code. i am surprised why this is not working want to see the same in my local machine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try something like

```
<s:property escape="false" value="bean.statusMsg"/>
```

As per my knowledge If you use the usual Struts property element for displaying data, it will escape html code. Hence, you have to turn off escaping:

Here are more details

[Struts2 Property tag](http://struts.apache.org/docs/property.html)

**Update**

I tried the property and its working perfectly either way. i tried it in two way create a property in my Action class  and also created a bean and the same property inside that bean

than i used the escapeHtml and it worked perfectly in both cases.
Additionally if you want to display data and show it in formatted way i am doubtful this is the right way to do this.
My suggestion is better use some CSS/HTML in your JSP to format the output rather than taking help from the property tag

To look in to the issue provide the code of your action and JSP classes.

Comment: I am using the escapeHtml value and I tried escape, setting both to "false" and the output from the property tag still seems to be escaping.

Comment: My deprecated knowledge since `escape` in-itself is deprecated.I should work.will test on my local machine only than can comment anything

Comment: Are you passing a Java String similar to what I am above?  I am still seeing the tags escaped and printed to the page.

Comment: Yes used same string same name can you show up in your post what you are expecting and what it is showing..will help you understand

Comment: @user1073570 yes i have used the same and it was creating line break when i used  escapeHtml="false" and was showing the text with HTML when  escapeHtml="true"

Comment: Problem Solved, I had somehow created two versions of the same file and I was editing the wrong version.  Thanks for the help.