# Display html text using Struts2

Tags: struts2

I have requirement to display data on jsp page using Struts2 and the data is in HTML tag form.

Eg. `<p> Ladies & gentelmen,<br> I am glad to announce my <font color="#CF0066">Retirement on this......</p>`

But I should see the following output (obviously without html tags):

**Ladies & gentelmen,
 I am glad to announce my Retirement on this......**

With Struts1, this use case work fine but I am not getting desired result with Struts2. I tried using `escapeXml` & `escapeHtml` attributes in `<s:property>` component but with no success

Comment: You don't show what you're using. Escaping HTML and/or XML is the solution, and AFAIK, it works just fine. So you'll need to include the *exact* string you're sending to the view layer, and the *exact* code you're using to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use escape attribute false for `<s:property>` tag

Try this

```
<s:property escape="false" value="Text"/>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8328255/876739